# Probability for a sequence of digits (inspired by amazing fact about pi): chances that starting at the n-th position you would find the number n

Tags: probability, combinatorics

*At the bottom of this post, I've explained what motivated me to ask this question - an entertaining mathematical observation, even if you choose to ignore the rest of this post.*

We have a random sequence of digits, $X_1$, $X_2$, ... where each $X_i$ is independently randomly selected from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}.

Choose integer $n \ge 1$.

What is the probability that for **all** integer $j$ satisfying $10^{n-1} \le j < 10^n$ the following condition is met:

$\large \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^{n-i-1}X_{j+i} \ne j$

In other words, the probability that for all $n$-digit integers j, the string of digits starting at position $j$ do **NOT** make the number $j$.  Call this probability $P_n$.

For $n = 1$, the answer is simple: $P_1 = (\frac{9}{10})^9 \approx 39\%$

For $n = 2$ and $n=3$, I've run a few random simulations, and it looks as if $P_n$ is around $40 \%$ in both cases.

Taking a naive approach, if we picked any particular $j$, the probability that the number string $X_j X_{j+1} X_{j+2} ... X_{j+n-1}$ does not equal j, would be $1-(\frac{1}{10})^n$, and the probability that this happened in $(10^n - 10^{n-1})$ independent trials would be

$\large [1-(\frac{1}{10})^n]^{10^n - 10^{n-1}}$ an expression which is around $40 \%$ for $n > 1$ (It rapidly converges to $e^{-0.9} \approx 40.7 \%$ as $n \to \infty$)

This isn't quite correct for $P_n$ because the n-digit numbers we are considering overlap, so are not independent, but maybe the dependence is weak enough that the naive approach is close to the correct answer.  I started to analyse the problem considering tree diagrams of possible outcomes, but it got messy and my question is whether there is a slicker way to crack the problem: how to calculate $P_n$ (or put some bounds on its value).

*I was prompted to consider this question, because I learnt that if you look at the decimal digits of $\pi$ (after the decimal place), the digits starting at the 36,541,622,473th place are 36541622473. Wow!  I know $\pi$ is not a random number but its digits have quasi-random properties and I was intrigued to know how likely it is to find such a result (or as I've posed the problem, how likely for no such result to occur). If my estimate is right, the chances are 60% so not that surprising, although it is impressive that someone found an 11-digit example.*

Comment: Just to add that the pi fact at the end of my question came from here and I am not in a position to verify it: https://twitter.com/pickover/status/1385414038423752707

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion should work, it seems (especially for bounds, one can simply do one level of exclusion followed by one level of inclusion). If I'm not mistaken, any two such "coincidence events" are either independent or mutually exclusive, so the inclusion step would be easy to calculate.

Comment: I should add that there is more on this phenomenon here: https://oeis.org/A057680.  It seems that the number of matches (where a string describes its own location) for n-digit numbers behaves (close to?) Binomial distribution B(10^n - 10^(n-1), 10^-n) which has a mean of 0.9, and so using Poisson approximation, prob of no matches is exp(-0.9) = 40.7%.  The mean of 0.9 is picked up in the comments in that OEIS link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we fix $n$ then the digits of interest are $(X_a, X_{r+1}, ... X_b)$ where $a = 10^{n-1}$ and $b=10^n+n-2$.  Let $T = b-a+1$

Define $D \subset \mathbb Z^{T}$ where $D=\{(x_a,...x_b):0 \le x_i \le 9 \}$

So $|D|=10^T$. $(X_a, X_{a+1}, ... X_b)$ is equally likely to be any member of $D$.

For $10^{n-1} \le j < 10^n$ (ie $j$ is an $n$-digit number), and $\mathbf x \in D$ we define $\lambda(j,\mathbf x)$ to be an indicator of a match, ie

$\lambda(j,\mathbf x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{lc}
            1 & \quad \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 10^{n-i-1}X_{j+i} = j \\
            0 & \text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.$

Because the condition $\lambda(j,\mathbf x) = 1$ fixes $n$ elements of $\mathbf x$, leaving the remaining $T-n$ elements to take any value from 0 to 9,

$\large \sum_{\mathbf x \in D} \lambda(j,\mathbf x) = 10^{T-n}$

The total number of matches over all $D$ is

$\large \sum_{\mathbf x \in D} \sum_{j=10^{n-1}}^{10^n-1} \lambda(j,\mathbf x) $

$=\large \sum_{j=10^{n-1}}^{10^n-1}  \sum_{\mathbf x \in D}  \lambda(j,\mathbf x)$

$=\large \sum_{j=10^{n-1}}^{10^n-1} 10^{T-n}$

$=(10^n-10^{n-1})10^{T-n}$

$=10^n(1-\frac{1}{10})10^{T-n}$

$=\frac{9}{10}10^T$

If we divide this by $|D|$ we obtain the mean number of matches, which is

$\frac{9}{10}$ or $0.9$.

Note how this is independent of $n$: on average, we expect just under 1 match among the 90 2-digit positions, and equally just under 1 match among the 9000 4-digit positions.

This indicates a match is a rare event, and although if one match occurs having a second match is not entirely independent, it is reasonable to approximate the number of matches as a Poisson distribution with mean $0.9$ (with the approximation improving rapidly as $n$ increases).  So, *approximately*:

Probability of no matches is $e^{-0.9} \approx 40.7\%$

Probability of one match is $e^{-0.9}0.9 \approx 36.6\%$

Probability of two matches is $\frac{e^{-0.9}0.9^2}{2} \approx 16.5 \%$

Probability of more than two matches is approximately $6.3 \%$

These are broadly confirmed by running some random simulations for $n=2$ and $n=3$.